# Can't use csv pipelines and images pipelines within a spider correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I'm trying to figure out any way to write first two fields in a csv file and to use the last two fields to download images in a folder simultaneously. I've created two custom pipelines to achieve that.

This is the spider:

```
import scrapy

class PagalWorldSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pagalworld'
    start_urls = ['https://www.pagalworld.pw/indian-pop-mp3-songs-2021/files.html']

    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'my_project.pipelines.PagalWorldImagePipeline': 1,
            'my_project.pipelines.CSVExportPipeline': 300
        },
        'IMAGES_STORE': r"C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\Images",
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for start_url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(start_url,callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.css(".files-list .listbox a[href]::attr(href)").getall():
            inner_page_link = response.urljoin(item)
            yield scrapy.Request(inner_page_link,callback=self.parse_download_links)

    def parse_download_links(self,response):
        title = response.css("h1.title::text").get()
        categories = ', '.join(response.css("ul.breadcrumb > li > a::text").getall())

        file_link = response.css(".file-details audio > source::attr(src)").get()
        image_link = response.urljoin(response.css(".alb-img-det > img[data-src]::attr('data-src')").get())
        image_name = file_link.split("-")[-1].strip().replace(" ","_").replace(".mp3","")
        
        yield {"Title":title,"categories":categories,"image_urls":[image_link],"image_name":image_name}
```

If I execute the script as is, I get all four fields in a csv file, the fields that I'm yielding within `parse_download_links` method. The script is also downloading and renaming images accurately.

***The first two fields `Title` and `categories` are what I wish to write to the csv file, not `image_urls` and `image_name`. However, this two fields `image_urls` and `image_name` are meant to download and rename images.***

How can I use both of the pipelines correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to create a CSV pipeline just for this purpose. Read [this](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-export-fields).

```py
import scrapy


class PagalWorldSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pagalworld'
    start_urls = ['https://www.pagalworld.pw/indian-pop-mp3-songs-2021/files.html']

    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            'my_project.pipelines.PagalWorldImagePipeline': 1,
            # 'my_project.pipelines.CSVExportPipeline': 300
        },
        'IMAGES_STORE':  r'C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\Images',
        'FEEDS': {
            r'file:///C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\output.csv': {'format': 'csv', 'overwrite': True}
        },
        'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ['Title', 'categories']
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for start_url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(start_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in response.css(".files-list .listbox a[href]::attr(href)").getall():
            inner_page_link = response.urljoin(item)
            yield scrapy.Request(inner_page_link, callback=self.parse_download_links)

    def parse_download_links(self,response):
        title = response.css("h1.title::text").get()
        categories = ', '.join(response.css("ul.breadcrumb > li > a::text").getall())

        file_link = response.css(".file-details audio > source::attr(src)").get()
        image_link = response.urljoin(response.css(".alb-img-det > img[data-src]::attr('data-src')").get())
        image_name = file_link.split("-")[-1].strip().replace(" ", "_").replace(".mp3", "")

        yield {"Title": title, "categories": categories, "image_urls": [image_link], "image_name": image_name}
```

Output:

```py
Heartfail - Mika Singh mp3 song Download PagalWorld.com,"Home, MUSIC, INDIPOP, Indian Pop Mp3 Songs 2021"
Fakir - Hansraj Raghuwanshi mp3 song Download PagalWorld.com,"Home, MUSIC, INDIPOP, Indian Pop Mp3 Songs 2021"
Humsafar - Suyyash Rai mp3 song Download PagalWorld.com,"Home, MUSIC, INDIPOP, Indian Pop Mp3 Songs 2021"
...
...
...
```

**EDIT:**

main.py:

```py
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings


if __name__ == "__main__":
    spider = 'pagalworld'
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings['USER_AGENT'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
    process.crawl(spider)
    process.start()
```

Comment: The script could not produce a csv file even when I executed it several times. I'm making the script run using crawlerprocess.

Comment: @MITHU I also used crawlerprocess and it works fine for me.

Comment: It perfectly worked out when I used `'output.csv': {'format': 'csv', 'overwrite': True}` instead of `r'C:\Users\WCS\Desktop\output.csv': {'format': 'csv', 'overwrite': True}` even when the address is correct @SuperUser. Can you give an idea what might be the issue? Thanks.

Comment: When I ran it on my machine I only used `output.csv` and not the absolute path, and when I copied it to the answer I changed it (and also the project's name) to match yours, but I forgot something important: `file:///`. @MITHU see the edit, it should work now with the path you wanted =)

Comment: Yep, it fixed the issue. No way!!! Thanks a trillion.